# Is "Android emulator icons with extremely large size" as of now compatible with the guidelines of SO?

Tags: discussion, reopen-closed

A few days ago I came by [Android emulator icons with extremely large size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35159059/android-emulator-icons-with-extremely-large-size) and because initially it did not even feature a screenshot, it was closed as unclear 4 hours after creation.

Now I saw potential in it and in the comments persuaded the asker to edit and improve his question. He did! Moreover, the questions seems to be on-topic now, after all it is about a tool used for programming.

So I voted for reopen and since two days the question only gathered one more reopen vote while the reopen voting queue is fairly empty. Especially [πάντα ῥεῖ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/316463/1536976) emphasized again that voters can vote any way they want.

It seems the on-topicness of this question is disputed. A clarification or consensus about whether it is on-topic or off-topic might support a reopening of the question. Being a question about a programming tool, it seems to be within the scope, but obviously others seem to think differently. Also it is quite clear to me, but others may still see some unclarity.

So my question:

Is this question compatible with the guidelines of SO?

**Edit:** This question has been edited after initial negative reception. Especially it was "Why has ... not been reopened?" and is now "Is ... now compatible with the guidelines?".

Comment: Btw. the question seems to be a puzzle (not simple to answer), so if anyone knows the answer I guess the asker would be fairly happy to get some input.

Comment: Why do you suspect this already automatically qualifies a question for reopening?

Comment: There are close to 12,000 questions every day.  If somebody flubs the first version then the odds he'll be crowded out by *thousands* of new questioners that want help are rather high off course.  Better get it right the first time.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ What do you mean by this?

Comment: `@HansPassant You basically say the reopen feature is void. These aren't the SO rules I know.

Comment: @Trilarion Just voting for reopening doesn't guarantee the question will actually be reopened. So what?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I didn't assume it would automatically qualify the question for reopening but I thought that if the question is indeed ontopic and if the queue is empty there should not be much between the question and its reopening. And if it should be under disput if the question is ontopic than meta is the place to discuss this. So coming here should be the natural solution.

Comment: @Trilarion As said in the SOCVR: users can use close/reopen votes how they want, it's not '*reopen-this-question-or-I-stab-you*'. Users may disagree that the question should be reopened and may not wish to cast a reopen vote. If you want to discuss the possibility of reopening/closing a question, try the various chat-rooms.

Comment: @cybermonkey I know that users can close/reopen as they like and I can imagine that others may just think this question should remain closed. I think it's ontopic and should be open and I think meta is the place to discuss this. What do you think?

Comment: Sorry for the initial negative impression of the question. I tried to improve it.

Comment: To wrap it up: This was a rather more unpleasant experience of my interaction with StackOverflow. I still think a kind of obvious mistake has been made repeatedly which seems sad to me. The question may have been in some way a gray area, it was reopened but then quickly been closed again for another close reason (maybe with the help of the glorious SOCVR). The new close reason didn't fit much better than the old one. Now the question does not exist anymore. I did all I could do to do what I think is right and undoubtedly others did what they thought was right from their side too.

Comment: What I liked least, however, was the lack of willingness to discuss the content and reasons for closure here as well as the drive-by downvotes well below -5 which were totally unnecessary and did not correlate with the quality of the question in my eyes. In the end I see it as an error but of course other will see it differently and SO can, of course, not be error proof. The only little thing that changed: I did not find the motivation to actively participate in the close vote review system since then.

Answer (score 5):

> Why is it taking so long to reopen that question (note the last comment of the asker where he very politely asks the closers to reconsider) or what am I missing?

Most probably because the question couldn't gather enough reopening votes despite being edited and trying to clarify.

The clarification might not be sufficient, or users don't see how that question will be sufficient or anyhow useful for future research.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. You convinced me to reformulate the question. Actually I'm more interested in finding out if the question is ontopic or not. I guess I didn't make it clear enough but I will try better now.

Comment: I don't think its off topic.  Tools questions are on topic, this is asking how to use a common dev tool (the android emulator).  I voted to reopen, as I think its a valid question.  I'm not sure he'll get an answer though.

Comment: I have voted up this question, as even I am facing this issue, after installing "Phonegap" on my system, my emulator too seems similar. I guess, this question deserves to be reopened. Also while I try to connect to the emulator using adb, it says target machine actively refused it. Still looking for the solution.